# Monogame Pipeline Error on Mac: System.DllNotFoundException: libfreeimage.dylib

Tags: macos, xamarin, mono, pipeline, monogame

I started a new project and I use Monogame (Pipeline) and the Xamarin Studio on my Mac. I installed Mono, Xamarin Studio and the latest version of Monogame (including Pipeline) for Mac. I've created a new Monogame project via Xamarin and everything worked fine.

Now I want to add a picture to my project via Pipeline. I added it to the project and pressed "Build". Sadly I get an Error.

The Error Message looks like this:

```
Importer 'TextureImporter' had unexpected failure!
System.DllNotFoundException: libfreeimage.dylib
```

Looks like libfreeimage is missing but I wasn't able to find a solution for this yet.

It works perfectly on my Windows.

Thanks

EDIT:

Fixed by installing the stand alone version for Mac.

Answer (score 3):

You can install the library using [Brew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install freeimage
```

Comment: I fixed it earlier by installing the stand alone version.

Answer (score 2):

I will expand on [Juraj Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44452910/14266151) as just brew installing freeimage didn't work for me.
Step 1: `brew install freeimage`
Step 2: Create a symbolic link to libfreeimage.dylib in one of the directories searched by mgcb.
For example: `sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew/Cellar/freeimage/3.18.0/lib/libfreeimage.dylib /usr/local/lib/libfreeimage`

Comment: yes! I had to do this linking too.